# Google Email Audit API - Create a mailbox for export error

Tags: google-api, google-api-client, google-api-java-client, google-email-audit-api

We're trying to request a mailbox download from Google, we're sending the request to the following URL :

https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/compliance/audit/mail/export/dev-gpanel.com/andrew

However, after this, we received the following error :

> ```
> EntityDoesNotExist(1301): andrew@dev-gpanel.com
>     at com.google.gdata.data.appsforyourdomain.AppsForYourDomainException.narrow(AppsForYourDomainException.java:133)
>     at com.google.gdata.client.appsforyourdomain.AppsForYourDomainService.insert(AppsForYourDomainService.java:102)
>     at com.promevo.beyond.server.impl.AuditServiceImpl.createGmailExport(AuditServiceImpl.java:150)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> ```

The user `andrew@dev-gpanel.com` does exist.

The weird thing is that this actually DOES create the request (as it is returned in the feed for getting all download requests).

Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/apps/NuuzjCQLahM;context-place=topicsearchin/apps/authorid$3AAPn2wQcDNTGfzF82TpIBq7Wy24U6AdM-Lj2c-_F78GxRm_mZqFLNW2jTYcWeG_qRqLjbx3UuBbTB%7Csort:date%7Cspell:false), `EntityDoesNotExist` error occurs when there is a another Google account somewhere using the same username already.

> Workaround for now is apparently to create them by hand, once they are in the system they will sync ok.
>
> I'm going to try using the GAM tool to batch import them all via a script since that should work (like this: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-manager/wiki/BulkOperations).

You may also check this [link](https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&ved=0ahUKEwjXiMiU9v_XAhUIsJQKHek8DK8QFgg0MAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgroups.google.com%2Fd%2Ftopic%2Fgoogle-apps-manager%2Fwb-6GWzupE8&usg=AOvVaw3sK62B4WNzaGNqefeSn0kV) as additional reference.